# Why does calling closed_callback not working in my python eel program?

Tags: python, user-interface, software-design, eel

I have been trying to make a app using python eel for my ui. I have been finding when i close the ui window, the progarm does not stop.  So I added `close_callback`. This has not helped and the app still runs when you close the ui window.

Code:

```
eel.init("ui")
def close_callback():
    exit()

eel.start("index.login.html", close_callback=close_callback ,disable_cache=True,block=True)
```

Thanks